# How do I edit my Arqade account?

Tags: discussion

I was wandering if you can, and how you can, edit your Arqade account. So far I only want to change my name and picture.

Comment: Welcome to the arQAde! If you have questions about the site itself, [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go (your question was migrated here by other users)

Answer (score 1):

Click on your profile, then on edit. But if you want to fully edit your profile, you need to register with an account, e.g. via your e-mail address, OpenID, Facebook or Google account. That way you will also be able to log in from other computers (or the one you currently use if you happen to delete the cookie).

Comment: @Seven Silly me, that's what I use...